# How to use public methods that are not static?

Tags: java, methods, instance, public

I have this method:

```
public Route getSubroute(int startOffset, int endOffset) {
    if (!(0 <= startOffset && startOffset < endOffset && endOffset <= this.getLength())) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Subroute is out of bounds.");
    }
    // the sub-segments that will make up the sub-route
    List<Segment> subsegments = new ArrayList<>();
    // variable offset is the distance along the route to the start of the
    // segment currently being examined
    int offset = 0;
    for (Segment segment : segments) {
        if (startOffset - offset < segment.getLength() && 0 < endOffset - offset) {
            // part of the segment belongs on the sub-route
            int subsegmentStartOffset = segment.getStartOffset() + Math.max(startOffset - offset, 0);
            int subsegmentLength = (Math.min(endOffset - offset, segment.getLength()) - Math.max(startOffset - offset, 0));
            subsegments.add(new Segment(segment.getSection(), segment.getDepartingEndPoint(), subsegmentStartOffset, subsegmentStartOffset + subsegmentLength));
        }
        offset += segment.getLength();
    }
    return new Route(subsegments);
}
```

And I'm trying to call this method in another class. I know I have to make an instance of it, but i dont know what I'm doing wrong. Here's as far as I get before I start getting errors:

```
public Route subRouteV(int startOffset, int endOffset){
        Route newRoute = new Route();
        Route vSubR = Route.getSubroute(startOffset, endOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to call `getSubroute` on the object that you created (`newRoute`), not on the class:

```
Route vSubR = newRoute.getSubroute(startOffset, endOffset);
```